# How to say create procedure if not exists in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, exists

I am trying to create a procedure in a MySQL database, but I want to check if it exists first.

I know how to do it for a table but when I use the same syntax for a stored procedure it doesn't compile.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 48):

Just drop the procedure if it does exist and then re-add it:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_procedure;
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure()
```

Comment: This is not an ideal solution. It's not guaranteed that the old procedure is the same as the new one, and we would be destroying the old one permanently if so.

Comment: By the way, this is ok only if done manually from a single connection. In case of concurrency, there is no guarantee that somebody re-creates the same procedure between your `DROP` and `CREATE` statements.

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.proc p WHERE db = 'db_name' AND name = 'stored_proc_name');
```

So you could do:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.proc p WHERE db = 'db_name' AND name = 'stored_proc_name') THEN
....
END IF;
```

Comment: My MYSQL query argues "END IF;" - I had to remove this line.

Comment: This is the way-too-primitive way of doing it.

Comment: `mysql.proc` no longer exists as of MySQL 8.0.

Comment: following up, it is now `SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.ROUTINES where routine_name = 'stored_proc_name';`

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't exist.  We had to write a stored procedure that mimics the same functionality.  Basically we create stored procedures by calling a stored procedure that does the "if exists" check.

Answer (score 3):

mySQL 8 allows to check for existence within the create statement using IF NOT EXISTS.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = user]
    PROCEDURE [IF NOT EXISTS] sp_name ([proc_parameter[,...]])
    [characteristic ...] routine_body

CREATE
    [DEFINER = user]
    FUNCTION [IF NOT EXISTS] sp_name ([func_parameter[,...]])
    RETURNS type
    [characteristic ...] routine_body
```

Comment: Notice that this feature is only available from MySQL 8.0.29 onwards as per the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html. A fact that you should provide

Answer (score -1):

Just call the procedure

```
CALL my_procedure();
```

if you get the specific error

> PROCEDURE yourDB.my_procedure does not exist

you can now react to "Error Code : 1305" and create the missing procedure:

CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure()
BEGIN
...
END

Comment: Calling existing procedure may affect database inconsistency (unwanted actions)

Comment: Still this answer is relevant: just change it into "just create the procedure" and react to error 1304 (stored procedure already exists). By the way, since MySQL **is not transational** when it comes to DDL queries, than this is actually the only sane way to avoid TOCTOU problems.