# Create a stored procedure only if the procedure does not exist in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

In SQL Server I am able to achieve this using dynamic sql string, but now I need to do the same thing for mysql but am getting nowhere, is there any way to achive this

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mysql.proc p WHERE NAME = 'stored_proc_name')
BEGIN
  DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE justATest()
    BEGIN
 -- some SP logic here
    END$$
END
```

I am storing the whole sql as a string inside a database column and execute the statement using a prepared statement `Execute` inside another stored procedure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a stored procedure exists before creating it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072086/how-to-check-if-a-stored-procedure-exists-before-creating-it)

Comment: I think the link you've provided is for Sql Server rather than mysql

Answer (score 0):

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.proc p WHERE db = 'db_name' AND name = 'stored_proc_name') THEN
....

taken from

[Older Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948713/how-to-say-create-procedure-if-not-exist-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Control statements like if then else are only allowed inside Stored Procedures in MySQL (unfortunately). There are usually ways around this, but it depends *why* you are conditionally creating the sproc.

E.g. If you're trying to avoid errors when running build scripts because sprocs already exist then you can use a conditional drop statement prior to your create like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS justATest;
CREATE PROCEDURE justATest()
BEGIN
  -- enter code here

END;
```

This will ensure the any changed code gets run (rather than skipped).