# Check if procedure exists before create on mysql

Tags: mysql

I have really big problem with create procedures on mysql.
I need to check if procedure exists before create it.
I can't drop and create (zero downtime issue).

MySql doesn't support 'if' conditions outside stored procedure, so query like in sql doesn't work.

I've tried both examples from this site : https://gist.github.com/jeremyjarrell/6083251

But it doesn't work.

Is there any possibility to check procedure?

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948713/how-to-say-create-procedure-if-not-exist-in-mysql

Comment: I've tried this solution. So it is no duplicate.

Comment: In what way does [this answer at that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9949094/207421) not answer your question?

Comment: First answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948713/how-to-say-create-procedure-if-not-exist-in-mysql works fine to me, do you have proper user privileges to view table mysql.proc?

Comment: Ok, I got result. But with this result I need to define to create procedure or not. With this point I have problem.

Comment: Let's clarify your issue.  You're trying to do this from a SQL *script file* rather than from a program you've written, in some other language, which could connect to MySQL, execute the `SELECT` query, and then use logic in the program to decide whether to create the procedure.  Since you are in a SQL script environment (and not running MariaDB), you have no conditional logic available to you... so just blindly trying to create the script throws an error if the script isn't there... is that correct?